# Only process the buffered channel when it is full

Tags: go, goroutine, channel

I want to process all the elements of the buffered channel, only when it is completely full. I couldn't use for-range because it would need closing the channel else it would throw deadlock. I need to keep the channel open for next set of batch. Is this approach ok? I am passing length in the param because channel is still getting data and I want to process everything in order.

```golang
func flush(chnMap map[string]chan string) {
    for _, v := range chnMap {
        if len(v) == CAP {
            go processChan(v, len(v))
        }
    }
}

func processChan(chn <-chan string, length int) {
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        op := <-chn
        //process chan
    }
}
```

Comment: _I couldn't use for-range because it would close the channel_ - No the range loop never closes anything, the channel isn't closed until its told so

Comment: You can simply check if the length of the channel is full and do a read with the range loop

Comment: @Inian for-range will throw deadlock if close is not called.

Comment: @Inian I need to keep channel open because it is being continuosly written.

Comment: Could you post a more demonstrative, reproducible example of the code you are dealing with? It is incorrect to say it will cause a deadlock. That can happen, if the channel is waiting for something to be written

Comment: I'm confused about the desired behavior. Do you want the channel to be emptied entirely before allowing additional writes?

Comment: @Woody1193 No not necessary, I just want it to be emptied when full. Strict requirement is to process in order of the inserts in channel.

Comment: what is `CAP`? also, a chan works like a queue, elements are processed in FIFO order. As long as there's only one receiver, you are guaranteed to process elements in the same order they are sent into the channel.

Comment: buffer your items into slice, check for its length to decide if it is time to treat all the accumulated items..

Answer (score -1):

I'd say your current solution is probably 95% correct. However, there are still some changes you could make:

```
func flush(chnMap map[string]chan string) {
    for _, v := range chnMap {
        if len(v) >= CAP {
            go processChan(v, len(v))
        }
    }
}

func processChan(chn <-chan string, length int) {
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        op := <-chn
        // process chan
    }
}
```

This code is more or less the same as what you have except that it will call `processChan` when `len(v)` is the same size as `CAP` or larger than `CAP`. This will cover the case where the channel is overfull when you check it for processing. You could of course handle this by giving your buffer an explicit capacity, but this will work without enforcing that design decision.